# How to disable the hide window animation

Tags: animations

I am on Ubuntu 21.04. I want to disable the hide animation where the window minimizes into the dock icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that would be:

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false

on a terminal window.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but is there a way to disable only the hide window animation and keep the others?